# Eliminating gap between super-scripted numbering and text in thebibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, superscripts, bibitem

I want to eliminate the gap between the reference text (such as 'First reference', 'Second reference' in the example below) and the reference super-scripted numbering (such as 1 and 2 in the example below). Please suggest an edit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{$^{#1}$}
\begin{document}
 Citing here \cite{AB} in the text.
    \begin{thebibliography}{100}
        \bibitem{AB}
        First reference.
        \bibitem{CD}
        Second reference.
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

The output of the code is:

[image: Code output with the gap problem between reference numbering and text.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type the following in the preamble:

```
\let\oldbibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}[1]{%
  \oldbibliography{#1}%
  \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}%
}
```

Result:

[image]